# Wicket - use map's entry values as objects in a model where I know the key for each component

Tags: java, web-applications, dictionary, wicket, wicket-1.6

I have a Java `Map` where I store data that has to be shown in a row in a table in a web application. I am using Wicket 6.

Is there a way to link Wicket Labels (which will be cells in my table) to the `String` version of an object in a `Map` knowing the key for each Label.

Should I implement my own version of `IModel` or is there any convenience class in the Wicket 6 libraries? As far as I can see there is none, but I could be wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement `IModel` also you can implement `IConverter<C>`.

To use custom converter override `Component#getConverter` like so:

```
   Label lbl = new Label("lbl"){
        @Override
        public <C> IConverter<C> getConverter(Class<C> type) {
            //return converter here
        }
    };
```

For components like `Label` you can implement only `convertToString` method.

Comment: Thanks for the IConverter suggestion for the String representation. I think I will end up implementing my own map's entry kind of model as I can't seem to find a readily available class.

Comment: note: IConverter is needed if change your label say to TextField

Comment: More info you can find in an excellent guide https://code.google.com/p/wicket-guide/ (see ch. 10.3)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no such `IModel` implementation at the current moment. It is not too hard to write your own `IModel<String>` that takes your `Map` and a `key` in the constructor and return the `String.valueOf(map.get(key))` ;)

Just make sure that either your `Map` is `Serializable` or otherwise, you should provide a `LoadableDetachableModel` for your map and use that.